# How to validate String value and String array values together? Using Optional syntax maybe?

Tags: java, arrays, string

l want to handle multiple validation, what do l need to handle exactly?

```java
String result = "John+Doe"; // value comes from third-party in this format
if(result != null) {
   String[] value = result.split("\\+");
   String name = value[0];
   String lastName = value[1];

   System.out.println(name);
   System.out.println(lastName);
}
```

This is default case what I expected and I handled this way
print will be John and Doe

Question is : what if `result` value is `JohnDoe` - one word, how to handle that to print that one word(value)?

Do I need to validate each value for `null` etc (name,lastname,value,result)? for example value.length > 0

How to combine all of that ? Not familiar with `Optional` from java 8?

Comment: Have you looked at what `result.split("\\+");` returns for `JohnDoe` and how it would affect the rest of the code above?

Comment: I'm afraid you have a real monster task to do if you want to validate possible name inputs provided by a third party... See [Falsehoods Programmers Believe About Names](https://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/)...

Comment: There are many ways to do this.  I’m pretty sure any approaches which use Optional will be too cumbersome to be useful.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please do not vandalize your posts.  By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right for SE to distribute that content (under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/)).  By SE policy, any vandalism will be reverted.

Answer (score 0):

In case you receive a String like `"JohnDoe"`  your String array will have only one element and an ArrayOutOfBounds exception will ocurr when you try to call `value[1]`. The additional checking you need to do, after splitting the String :

```
if(value.length<2) {
 // wrong input
 } else{
 // your code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple way could be:

```
String[] value = result.split("\\+");
String name = value[0];
String lastName = value.length>1? value[1] : "No last name found"; // or `""` an empty string
```

Assuming result itself is not null

Comment: Thanks, will be cleaner with java Optional.orElse?

Answer (score 0):

You could just check if the result contains the + sign. If it contains the plus sign then you have both name and lastName, if not you have only name:

```
       if(result != null) {
            String name;
            String lastName = "";
            if (result.contains("+")){
                String[] value = result.split("\\+");
                name = value[0];
                lastName = value[1];
            }else{
                name = result;
            }
            System.out.println(name);
            System.out.println(lastName);
        }
```

Output when `result = "John+Doe";`

```
John
Doe
```

Output when `result = "JohnDoe";`

```
JohnDoe
```

I do not think that Optional will make it more clear, but here is an example with Optional:

```
 if(result != null) {
                String[] value = result.split("\\+");
                String name = value[0];
                Optional<String> lastName = Optional.ofNullable(value.length>1?value[1]:null);

            System.out.println(name);
            if (lastName.isPresent()) {
                System.out.println(lastName.get());
            }
        }
```

The `lastName` could take either a `null` or a `String`. Then on System.out lines, you can check if lastName isPresent and print or not.

Comment: Thanks, will be cleaner with java Optional.orElse?

Comment: I wouldn't say that Optional could help in this case, but if you must use it, you can create a nullable Optional  for the lastName. If you can have a null or empty result String, you can use the Optional class for the name as well

Answer (score -1):

A simple way could be:

```
String result = "John+Doe";
        String s = Optional.ofNullable(result).orElse("");
        if (!s.trim().isEmpty()) {
            String[] value = result.split("\\+");
            if(value.length>1)
            {
                String name = value[0];
                String lastName = value[1];
                System.out.println(name);
                System.out.println(lastName);
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("invalid result=="+result);
            }

        }
```

Answer (score -1):

Using `Optional` can lead to:

```
String[] value = result.split("\\+");
Optional<String> name = Optional.ofNullable(value.length>0 && value[0].length()!=0 ? value[0] : null);
Optional<String> lastName = Optional.ofNullable(value.length>1 && value[1].length()!=0 ? value[1] : null);
System.out.println("Result is "
    +name.orElse("")
    +lastName.map(" ln:"::concat).orElse("")
);
```

With `JohnDoe` you'll have `Result is JohnDoe`

With `+JohnDoe` you'll have  `Result is ln:JohnDoe`

With `Jonn+Doe` you' ll have `Result is John ln:Doe`

`name` (or `lastname`) is an `Optional<String>` which means that either there is a value or no value at all (the parsing will detect the condition). Then you can use that `Optional` to generate any output you want in both cases.